# Image markdown - remove to re-add isn't smooth

Tags: feature-request, edits, markdown, images

If I edit a post to swap a quick phone snap for a properly cropped version, straightened & punched up in Photoshop to be more legible, better exposed [a dozen reasons I edit many photos a day where the original was poorly framed or exposed] then my order of action depends on the initial image description.

If there's just the placeholder, I can just select the line, delete & add my own edited image. Fine.

If the OP actually had used a true description, then I get stuck in a half-way house.

The markdown as I first see it [using quoted here to differentiate the image extents]

> [image]

I then select the line & click the 'picture' icon, which *almost* neatly removes the image & links, leaving the description alone… but not quite…

> [image]

I then need to tidy up the bit it missed, reselect the description & add the edited image.

Could that removal step be cleaned up to lose the last `![` which gets left behind?